# Why "מִי וָמִי" instead of "מִי וּמִי"?

Tags: hebrew, grammar-dikduk

I have always thought that as a general rule, the *vav* conjunctive prefix is usually a "וְ". But, when the word being "prefixed" either starts with a *shva* or starts with a "lip-letter" (בומ"פ), the *vav* changes to a "וּ" (*kubutz*).

However, I have come across a few of exceptions to the above rule, only one of which I actually remember at the moment. (Other examples are welcome as comments or as part of an answer.)

The exception I can think of right now is Exod. 10:8: "מִי וָמִי הַהֹלְכִים", in which I would think it should be "מִי וּמִי הַהֹלְכִים".

Why is it not "מִי וּמִי"? Is my above rule wrong or missing something, or is this just a particular exception, and if so, why?

Comment: Migrate to Hebrew.SE?

Comment: @WAF Unfortunately, probably true, even though I think I've found the answer.... :(

Comment: @HodofHod It's not so bad. They don't [_quite_](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/36772/hebrew-language-usage) exist. Answer away!

Comment: Probably only the vav with a schwa changes to oo

Comment: @WAF, I thought we're allowing Hebrew language questions here until beta starts for Hebrew.SE.

Comment: @DoubleAA, Well then, I guess the question is why is this a *vav* with a *kamatz* as a conjunctive?

Comment: @All, Anyone mind if I quote Hebrew grammar from a kofer, since I can't seem to find a Rabbinic source? Am I even allowed to? (Sounds like another question.)

Comment: @HodofHod, Please do. As per [here](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1573/using-christian-interpretations-in-answers), it seems acceptable, especially in a case like this, being that grammar seems to be a subject that has attracted more *apikorsim* than any other.

Comment: @jake It's pretty standard form for the last word in a list when its accent is on the first syllable eg בשר ודם. Linguistically I can't say more than that.

Comment: @WAF, Jake, I'm not actually sure, we seem to have closed quite a few purely Hebrew grammar questions before, http://judaism.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bgrammar-dikduk%5D+closed%3Ayes+is%3Aq. Also, http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/162/in-what-respects-are-hebrew-language-questions-in-scope?rq=1

Comment: I was going to close unilaterally as off-topic but then I saw there'd been some debate here already. So consider my vote cast for closure instead.

Comment: @msh210, Can we figure out what kind of Hebrew language questions are acceptable here? I just don't see a difference between [these](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bgrammar-dikduk%5D%5Bhebrew%5D+closed%3Ayes+is%3Aq) and many of [these](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bgrammar-dikduk%5D%5Bhebrew%5D+closed%3Ano+is%3Aq).

Comment: @jake, the two highest-voted answers at http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/162 (one of which is yours) seem to agree with one another, and state that Hebrew-language question that arise from Jewish life & learning are on-topic where was those that don't so arise aren't. I'm not sure that rule's been consistently applied, but that seems to be the rule the community's agreed upon. I suppose this question is acceptable, actually, then, and I'm glad I didn't close it. `:-)` (Shockingly,) I don't have time just now to examine old questions and close/open according to the rule.

Comment: @msh210, That's what I had previously assumed, that in general Biblical Hebrew is on topic here, having even asked a question or two on the topic in the past. Which is why I was surprised by WAF's and HodofHod's (and your) initial disapproval.

Comment: @jake, my initial disapproval was because the question asks about the construction in general, only bringing an example from _Tanach_, rather than using the _Tanach_ study as a motivation for the question. (And I don't agree with your restatement that Biblical Hebrew is on-topic. Questions on Jewish learning are on-topic, not questions about Biblical Hebrew in general.) I'm still uneasy about it, to be honest, but wouldn't vote to close. −1, though.

Comment: @msh210, [This](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/14259/versus) as well?

Comment: @jake, heehee, I upvoted that one. Call me inconsistent, I guess. `:-)`

Comment: @msh210, Well, hopefully Hebrew.SE will start up soon, and this whole issue will become moot. Chag Sameach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Gesenius](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilhelm_Gesenius), you [are mostly right](http://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Gesenius%27_Hebrew_Grammar/104#GHGpar-104-e). Usually, a vov will take a shuruk when preceding a labial consonant, as well as when preceding a simple shva. The exception seems to be when the vov is right before the accent, and the word is at the end of a clause, sentence, or group of nouns.

From [Wikisource](http://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Gesenius%27_Hebrew_Grammar/104#GHGpar-104-g):

> (*e*) Immediately before the tone-syllable [the Waw] frequently takes *Qameṣ*, like בְּ‎, כְּ‍‎, לְ‎ (see  §102f), but in most cases only at the end of a sentence or clause (but cf. also וָכֹא‎ 1 K 22<sup>30</sup>), e.g. וָמֵ֖ת‎ Ex 21<sup>12</sup> (on the other hand, in verse 20 וּמֵ֖תִ‎ is in closer logical connexion with what follows); 2 K 7<sup>4</sup> וָמַ֣הְנוּ שָׁ֔ם‎, וָמַ֑תָנוּ‎ and וָמָֽתְנוּ‎; Ru 3<sup>3</sup> וָסַֹכְתְּ‎; [Ps] 10<sup>15</sup> וָ֝רָֹע‎; 1 S 9<sup>4</sup> וָאַ֔יִן‎; 2 S 13<sup>26</sup> וָלֹ֔א‎; Ez 47<sup>9</sup> וָחָ֔י‎; cf. also (with *Ṭiphḥa*) Gn 33<sup>13</sup>, 2 S 15<sup>12</sup>. The very frequent connexion of nouns expressing kindred ideas, by means of וָ‎, is due simply to considerations of rhythm, for even in such cases the *Wāw* must immediately precede the tone-syllable, which must be marked by a disjunctive accent, e.g. תֹּ֫הוּ וָבֹ֫הוּ‎ Gn 1<sup>2</sup>, יוֹם וָלַ֫יְלָה‎ Gn 8<sup>22</sup> (see also the previous examples); Gn 13<sup>14</sup> (thrice); Ex 25<sup>3</sup> זָהָב נָכֶ֫סֶף‎; [Ps] 96<sup>7</sup> כָּבוֹד וָעֹז‎; [Ps] 76<sup>7</sup> וְרֶ֫כֶב וָסוּס‎; Gn 7<sup>13</sup> וְשֵׁם־וְחָם וָיֶ֫פֶת‎; נֹחַ‎ 1 K 21<sup>10</sup> כֹּה וָכֹה ;אֱלֹהִים וָמֶ֑לֶךְ‎ *thus and thus*; Est 1<sup>8</sup> אִישׁ־וָאִֽישׁ‎ at the end of the verse, but in [Ps] 87<sup>5</sup> אִישׁ וְאִישׁ‎ in spite of the *D<sup>e</sup>ḥi* with the second אִישׁ‎, because it is closely connected with the following predicate. Also with three words פַּ֫חַד וָפַ֫חַת וָפָ֑ה‎ Is 24<sup>17</sup>. [...]

Comment: I don't know if you want to edit the source, but this might be a better online presentation of Gesenius' grammar: http://www.davidcox.com.mx/library/G/Gesenius%20-%20Hebrew%20Grammar.pdf

Comment: @ShimonbM I don't see an appreciable difference there, am I missing something?

Comment: @HodofHod - No, just that the PDF has the whole document in one piece, and you can skip to individual sections without needing to go through it chapter-by-chapter. You can search as well, and I don't know how sophisticated the search feature on Wikisource is. But if they're much of a muchness, I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: @ShimonbM Ah, takeh, I was upset that Wikibooks had no ability to search in books. Thanks for your addition then! (I think I'll leave mine up too, though, since you don't have to load an entire pdf to view it.)

Comment: HodofHod, you may wish to copy-paste this pretty much verbatim as an answer to http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/44381.