# vowels on vav before mem

Tags: hebrew, grammar-dikduk, ki-teitzei

Can someone explain why the following examples, all from parashat ki tzetzeh - כִּי תֵצֵא, are written with a kamatz:

- "vamet"  - וָמֵת - ([D'varim 21:21](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9985#v=21))
- "vameta" - וָמֵתָה - ([D'varim 22:21](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9986#v=21))
- "vametu" - וָמֵתוּ - ([D'varim 22:24](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9986#v=24))

yet the following is written with a shuruk:

- "umetu" -  וּמֵתוּ - ([D'varim 22:22](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9986#v=22))

Comment: Hint: 22:22 is the only one you mentioned not on a hard pause.

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/27431/759