# The use of tsere yod in Psalm 2:3

Tags: grammar-dikduk, tehilim-psalms

I can understand most of the breakdown of the word מוסרותימו in Psalm 2, thanks to [your website](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/14259) viz masculine noun from root אסר with female plural ending ות. Also the poetic ending מו for 'their', but could someone please explain the tsere yod?

Answer (score 2):

I've just been researching pronouns, which I've always had problems understanding, and came across the answer to my own question!  The tsere yod being the link between a plural noun and the suffix (in this case 'their').
Hoping perhaps that finding the answer to my confusion will help someone else.