# Is there a difference between Simlah and Salmah?

Tags: words, clothing, mishpatim

In Parshat Mishpatim (22:8), the text, discussing guarded and stolen items, the list includes the word Salmah ("garment") which the Onkelos translates as "ksu". A similar word, Salmat, is used in 22:25. We also use the word when putting on the talit (from Tehillim 104:2, Oteh ohr kasalma).

Later, in 22:26, however, when discussing loans and collateral, the text suddenly uses the word Simlato (which Artscroll similary has as "garment" though the Onkelos has totvei). In that verse, the textual "k'suto" is translated into Aramaic as "k'sutei".

Is there any technical difference between the two garments which might have halachic or interpretive significance? [Rashi](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9883#showrashi=true) only draws the distinction between the k'suto (talit/cloak) and simlato (shirt).

Comment: Here's a link on [Aspaklaria](http://www.aspaklaria.info/300_SHIN/%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%94%20%20%20%D7%91%D7%92%D7%93.htm) containing three sources discussing the differences between "שמלה" and "שלמה".

Comment: [What about Salmah and Salmone?](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt2904.htm#21)

Comment: perhaps similar http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/5145/759

Comment: See Ibn Ezra on yesterday's parsha on returning a mashkon on a loan.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both Rav Hirsch and the Netziv point out the word change and explain that Salma signifies a more dignified form of clothing. 
Rav Hirsch connected it to Tzelem as in Tzelem Elokim.
Whereas Simla is simply clothing to cover ones nakedness.